# Recover a set of vectors from a Gram matrix that have conjugate symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, spherical-harmonics, cholesky-decomposition

I have a set of complex column vectors concatenated in a matrix, $X$, for which I have the corresponding Gram matrix $G = X^*X$.  Because of the basis that I'm using (complex spherical harmonics), the vectors have a conjugate symmetry that can be expressed as $\overline{X} = MX$ where

$M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$

Otherwise put, if we label the rows of $X$ as $-1, 0, 1$ then $X_{m, n} = (-1)^m \overline{X_{-m, n}}$.  Note that this symmetry guarantees that the Gram matrix is real.

Now, suppose I'm given only the Gram matrix, $G$, and I want to recover any corresponding set of vectors $X$ that obey this conjugate symmetry, how can I do this?

I've tried a Cholesky decomposition $G = LL^{*}$, but this gives triangular matrices which clearly don't fulfill the conjugate symmetry.  Then I thought that maybe I can combine my symmetry criterion with a rotation of $L$ somehow, i.e. $G = LQQ^*L^*$, and find a $Q$ that would rotate $L$ into the complex plane such that the symmetry criterion is satisfied.  But I couldn't find a way to do this.

After attempting various decompositions of the Gram matrix I couldn't find a way that would give me a suitable set of vectors.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas that you tried are pretty close.  For succinctness I assume $X$ has linearly independent columns.

You have $G=X^*X = \overline{X}^TX = (MX)^TX = X^TMX$.  So $G$ is Hermitian and symmetric and hence real.  Now run Cholesky over reals:
$G=LL^T$
then $X=QR$, with $R:=L^T$ and $Q$ is some unitary matrix that you may select.

$M(QR) = MX = \overline{X}= \overline{(QR)}= \overline{Q}R\implies MQ = \overline{Q}$
At this point, examining $M$ and $ MQ = \overline{Q}$ implies that row $2$ of $Q$ is real, and you just need to find rows 1 and 3 that are orthonormal to each other (and row 2) and are negative conjugates of each other.  So for example you may select,
$Q:= \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot i \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot i
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Can you help me to understand if there is any direct connection between your $Q$ matrix and the eigendecomposition of $M$ which I noticed has a similar structure (eigenvalues $[1, -1, 1]$, eigenvectors $[\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}, \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}, 0]$, $[0, 0, 1]$, $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}, \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}, 0]$).

Comment: This is problematic.  You wrote $M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$ and are now saying $[0, 0, 1]$ is an eigenvector of $M$ -- *this is false*. I would guess you are looking at something permutation similar to $M$ but this muddies the waters.  For what it's worth I chose this $Q$ out of convenience, without looking at the eigenvectors of $M$.

Comment: Sorry, I miscopied the outputs from my eigensolver: I read the rows instead of columns. $M$ is correct, the (normalised) eigenvectors are $[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0, -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}]$, $[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}]$ and $[0, 1, 0]$.  But I presume the similarity with your $Q$ (albeit with a two terms real that you have as complex) is just a coincidence.

Comment: Here's one way to interpret this -- again not necessary but maybe helpful.  Suppose $M=Q\Lambda Q^T$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with two 1s and then a -1 in final spot.  And let $D$ be diagonal with two 1s and an i in final spot. Note $\Lambda^2=I$ and $D^2=\Lambda$. Now $U:=QD^*$ or $UD=Q$ so $U$ is matrix that collects these real orthogonal eigenvectors that you've stated.  Now using $G=X^TMX=(QR)^TM(QR)$ we can plug the above in to get $G=(UDR)^TM(UDR)=R^TD(U^TMU)DR=R^T(D\Lambda D) R=R^TR$  and as before $R=L^T$ from Choleksy.